# Setting text and binary buffer size for tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, atmosphere

I have a web application which sends a large text payload over Atmosphere using websocket to GWT client. The payload size exceeds 8192 bytes, which is default buffer size for both text and binary buffer for websocket by tomcat. If payload exceeds the buffer limit then client receives as it is broken to 8192 bytes only.

I tried increasing the buffer size by setting the context parameters in web.xml as follows,

```
      <context-param>
         <param-name>org.apache.tomcat.websocket.textBufferSize</param-name>
         <param-value>32768</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.tomcat.websocket.binaryBufferSize</param-name>
            <param-value>32768</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

But its not getting reflected for tomcat 7.0.47.

Can someone help if am I missing anything or should I use latest 7.x tomcat version?

I don't want to migrate to tomcat 8, as my application libraries will be impacted because of it.

Thanks,
Shailesh